# factor $x^6+x^3+1 $ into a product of 1st or 2nd degree polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I've got this polynomial: $x^6+x^3+1 $

And i have to factor it into a few 1st or 2nd degree polynomials with real coefficients.

Comment: Factor first $y^2+y+1=(y-r_1)(y-r_2)$. Then factor $x^3-r_1=(x-\sqrt[3]{r_1})(x-\sqrt[3]{r_1}w)(x-\sqrt[3]{r_1}w^2)$ and $x^3-r_2=(x-\sqrt[3]{r_2})(x-\sqrt[3]{r_2}w)(x-\sqrt[3]{r_2}w^2)$. Finally multiply the factors that have complex roots that are conjugates of each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the cyclotomic polynomial of order nine. You see that easily from the calculation $$(x^6+x^3+1)(x^3-1)=x^9-1.$$
Therefore the complex roots of the sextic are the numbers $e^{2\pi ik/9}$, $\gcd(k,9)=1$. The gcd-condition comes from the fact that if that gcd were $>1$ then we would have a root of $x^3-1$.

Anyway, you get quadratic factors with real coefficients by pairing up the complex conjugates $k\leftrightarrow -k$. For example
$$
(x-e^{2\pi i/9})(x-e^{-2\pi i/9})=x^2-(e^{2\pi i/9}+e^{-2\pi i/9})x+1=x^2-2\cos\frac{2\pi}9x+1.
$$
Leaving the other two factors to you.